# How do your set the twitter byline from an application?

Tags: python, api, twitter

Twitter allows applications to set a "byline" that appears after the tweeter's name, but I don't see how to set that. I'm currently using the Python API tweepy. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to register the application with Twitter, IIRC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set User-Agent in python-twitter ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803669/how-to-set-user-agent-in-python-twitter)

Comment: No, this isn't about HTTP headers, and I already have the app registered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### How do I get “from [MyApp]” appended to updates sent from my API application?
>
> We now recommend developers use OAuth
> to perform authentication with the
> API. When applications use OAuth,
> Twitter automatically knows the source
> of status updates. We are therefore
> able to append source attribution
> (from "[MyApp]") to tweets. If you
> would like tweets from your
> application to receive a source
> parameter, please register an
> application and implement OAuth
> authentication. We will automatically
> include your application as the source
> for any tweets sent from your
> application.
>
> We originally allowed applications to
> create a source parameter for
> non-OAuth use but that has been
> discontinued. Applications pre-OAuth
> source parameters will remain active,
> but new registrations are no longer
> accepted.

[This FAQ tells you everything](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/api_faq#attribution).

Comment: I hadn't seen that, but this must not be the whole story as have tweets working from my registered app via OAuth, but they are still missing the byline. But maybe they will show up later...

Comment: @alex: That is how tweets would be listed with BasicAuth but now OAuth is required it should be something else. I'm curious what D.S. Blank is seeing if not his apps name.

Comment: It doesn't show anything... it is as if the tweets are from me (the account against which the oauth is used). For example, see:

Comment: http://twitter.com/#!/doug_blank  None of the top tweets (as of Feb 12, 2011) are from me, but from my code as described above. The "from" never did kick in.

Comment: The "via gramps-tweet" is now showing. Thanks to all for suggestions.